# My AngularJS code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am learning AngularJS and ended up with the following code for ToDoList basic app. I viewed it in a browser it didn't work. I am new to the Angular and mightn't get obvious things, so I thought if my app name is

```
todoApp
```

Then I should put

```
$scope.todoApp
```

instead of

```
$scope.todo
```

but turned out that's not an issue.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="todoApp">
  <head>
    <title>To DO List</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var model = {
             user: "Adam",
             items: [{ action: "Buy flowers", done: false },
                    { action: "Get Shoes", done: false },
                    { action: "Collect Tickets", done: true },
                    { action: "Call Joe", done: false }]
            };
         var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []);

         todoApp.controller("ToDoCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.todo = model;
          });
    </script>
  </head>
 <body ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
   <div class="page-header">
     <h1>
        {{todo.user}}'s To Do List
        <span class="label label-default">{{todo.items.length}}</span>
     </h1>
   </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Done</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="item in todo.items">
                <td>{{item.action}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done" /></td>
                <td>{{item.done}}</td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

That's what I get in a browser..[image]

And that's what I guess I am supposed to get...[image]

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Any error in console?? You are missing `"` in style sheet.

Comment: SO try toDoApp instead

Answer (score 2):

Your `HTML` getting invalid because you are missing `"` in link tag's `rel` attribute. Here you are missing:

```
<link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet>
                                                ^ ==> missing "
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/vbV0BU7A7Kj6SfrkNBPf?p=preview) `/* updated css */`

Have a look at Invalid HTML in [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cGptAxRukwjVKN3JlSKr?p=preview). Here you can see after `link` tag HTML is colored green.

Comment: Yep @AlexandraProdan. This is also important aspect.